# Convert preg_match pattern to javascript pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

Any one can help converting this php regex pattern to js compatible one?

```
$delimiter = "-";
$phone = "some number from the client";
var_dump(
    preg_match($phone,"|^([0-9]{1,3}".$delimiter."[0-9]{1,4}".$delimiter."[0-9]{4,12}(#[0-9]{1,4})?)$|")
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like to keep and reject?

Comment: (1-2numbers)-(1-2numbers)-(7-9numbers + avoid start with 0 + avoid repeats 1111111 + avoid 1234567) without the brace. this is a phone number verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var delimiter = "-",
    phone = "8-989-895",
    re = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,3}"+delimiter+"[0-9]{1,4}"+delimiter+"[0-9]{4,12}(?:[0-9]{1,4})?$");
console.log(re.test(phone));
```